# Narayana-Zidek-Capell numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

Generate the *n*th [Narayana-Zidek-Capell](https://oeis.org/A002083) number given an input *n*. Fewest bytes win.

f(1)=1, f(n) is the sum of the previous floor(n/2) Narayana-Zidek-Capell terms.

Test Cases:

```
f(1)=1

f(9)=42

f(14)=1308

f(15)=2605

f(23)=664299
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! This is a nice first challenge. Though it's ultimately up to you, typically we recommend waiting at least a week to accept an answer. Having an accepted answer early on can send a signal to other users that the challenge is more or less over, which discourages them from participating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Jelly, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
HĊrµṖß€Sȯ1
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=SMSKcsK14bmWw5_igqxTyK8x&input=&args=OQ)

Takes `n` as argument and prints the result.

#### Explanation

```
H              divide input by 2
 Ċ             round up to get first n to recurse
  r            inclusive range from that to n
   µ           (chain separator)
    Ṗ          remove n itself from the range
     ß€        call self recursively on each value in the range
       S       sum results
        ȯ1     if sum was zero, return one
```

Comment: Stumbled across this old answer. I found a couple of saves. Firstly the trailing `1` is redundant since the argument will be one in the case it is used. Secondly, we can take the second "half" of the range from zero to `n` to get the same list of numbers as `HĊrµṖ` gets us which is `ḶŒHṪ` - [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm1HJ3k83Lnq8PxHTWuCT6z/f7gdyPj/39AIAA)

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby, <s>34</s> 32 bytes

This uses a formula from the OEIS page for the [Narayana-Zidek-Cappell numbers](https://oeis.org/A002083).

**Edit:** Got rid of parentheses using operator precedence with thanks to feersum and Neil.

```
f=->x{x<4?1:2*f[x-1]-x%2*f[x/2]}
```

Comment: Surely you don't need parentheses for `x%2`?

Comment: Well, not if you put `x%2*` at least.

Comment: @feersum and Neil Thank you both

Comment: Previous question edits suggested that the formula was `x<2?`... this makes it much clearer thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, <s>48</s> <s>42</s> <s>38</s> 36 bytes

Algorithm taken from the OEIS page. `n<3` may be changed to `n<4` with no effect. Returns the `n`th number, where `n` is a positive integer.

```python
a=lambda n:n<3or 2*a(n-1)-n%2*a(n/2)
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/Caic/1)

Answer (score 5):

### 05AB1E, 16 bytes

An iterative solution as 05AB1E doesn't have functions.

```
X¸sGDN>;ï£Os‚˜}¬

X¸               # initialize a list with 1
  sG          }  # input-1 number of times do
    D            # duplicate current list
     N>;ï£       # take n/2 elements from the list
          O      # sum those elements
           s‚˜   # add at the start of the list
               ¬ # get the first element and implicitly print
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=WMK4c0dETj47w6_Co09z4oCay5x9wqw&input=MjM)

Answer (score 5):

## C, 38

A translation of the OEIS algorithm. There's just not enough C code around here!

```
f(n){return n<3?:2*f(n-1)-n%2*f(n/2);}
```

Comment: How does `n<3?:(...)` work?

Comment: It's a GCC extension (seems to work in clang too) that evaluates to the conditional itself if the middle expression is missing. See [the relevant GCC page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html) and [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559705/ternary-operator-without-the-middle-expression) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 67 bytes

```
def f(n):
 x=1,
 for i in range(n):x+=sum(x[-i//2:]),
 print(x[-1])
```

A function that takes input via argument and prints to STDOUT. This is a direct implementation of the definition.

**How it works**

```
def f(n):               Function with input target term index n
 x=1,                   Initialise term list x as tuple (1)
 for i in range(n):...  For all term indices in [0,n-1]...
 x[-i//2:]              ..yield the previous floor(i/2) terms...
 x+=sum(...)            ...and append their sum to x
 print(x[-1])           Print the last term in x, which is the nth term
```

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/0eYDHI)

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
L|syM>/b2Ub1
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%7CsyM%3E%2Fb2Ub1%0Ay&input=9&debug=0) [Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%7CsyM%3E%2Fb2Ub1%0Ay&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A9%0A14%0A15%0A23&debug=0)

Defines a function `y(n)` that returns the `n`th Narayana-Zidek-Capell-number.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 38 bytes

```
If[#<4,1,2#0[#-1]-#~Mod~2#0[(#-1)/2]]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes  as input and returns () as output. Based off of the Ruby solution.

Comment: There's no built in?

Comment: @Insane No, there's no built-in.

Comment: Simply amazing!

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 34 bytes

```
f 1=1
f n=sum$f<$>[n-div n 2..n-1]
```

Usage example: `f 14` -> `1308`.

A direct implementation of the definition.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 63 Bytes

```
int z(int n){return n<3?1:n%2>0?(2*z(n-1)-z(n/2)):(2*z(n-1));}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Go, 63 bytes

```
func f(i int) int{if(i<4){return 1};return 2*f(i-1)-i%2*f(i/2)}
```

Pretty much a direct port from the C answer

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 81 bytes

This is a full program without recursion. A recursive function can be defined in 52 bytes (it might be possible to beat that) but that's just a pretty boring port of sherlock9's answer (and it errors if you ask for f(100) or more) so I'm putting up this longer and more interesting version

```
<?php for($i=$argv[1];$j=$i;$i--)for(;--$j*2>=$i;)$a[$j]+=$a[$i]?:1;echo$a[1]?:1;
```

Causes many (O[n]) notices but that's fine.

Comment: `O(n)` notices? Huh?

Comment: notices are a non critical error type that don't stop execution and are commonly silenced in production environments. whenever you try to get the value of an undeclared variable or an undefined offset in an array you get a notice. This program tries to get the value of O[n] undefined offsets (and a couple of undeclared variables too) so you get O[n] notices.

Answer (score 0):

## R, 55 bytes

```
x[1]=1;for(i in 2:10){x[i]=sum(x[i-1:floor(i/2)])};x[9]
```

Change `10` in the `for` loop and `x[9]` to get whichever index the user wants.

Comment: Here's a recursive version that is 54 bytes long:

`f=function(n)ifelse(n<4,1,2*f(n-1)-n%%2*f(floor(n/2)))`

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <del>54</del> 52

```
f=n=>Math.round(n<3?1:2*f(n-1)-n%2*f(parseInt(n/2)))
```

Based on the [C](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85190/13486) answer.

- Saved 2 bytes by using `parseInt` instead of `Math.floor`

Answer (score 0):

### Maple, <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```
`if`(n<4,1,2*f(n-1)-(n mod 2)*f(floor(n/2)))
```

Usage:

```
> f:=n->`if`(n<4,1,2*f(n-1)-(n mod 2)*f(floor(n/2)));
> seq( f(i), i = 1..10 );
  1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 22, 42, 84
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 63 bytes

```
f=function(n,a=0)if(n<2)1 else{for(i in n-1:(n%/%2))a=a+f(i);a}
```

`a=0` is added as a default because it saves me two curly brackets. Function recursively calls itself as needed.